# How to get a single value from array using bash without loop

Tags: bash

Is it possible to get a single value from array without a loop?

I have a script under a variable which output similar array:

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]
```

Now I want to get value B using variable so I did:

```
echo ${script[1]}
```

but it displayed nothing.

Comment: That's not bash array syntax. Extend this into a [mcve] that shows us how the value is assigned so we can see if it's **really** an array.

Comment: (What "a script under a variable" means is similarly unclear. Scripts can't "output" arrays in any meaningful way; they write character streams to stdout, which can then be parsed into arrays, but the code you're using for all of that is pertinent).

Comment: ...or, to check if it's an array yourself, run `declare -p script`. If `script` is really an array, that will output `declare -a script=( [0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D" )`. If it writes `declare -- script='[ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]'`, then you don't have an array at all, you have a *string* with JSON syntax inside it.

Comment: ...it's certainly possible to convert a JSON string to a bash array (best done with `jq` parsing the former into a NUL-delimited stream), but that would need to be a different question.